# IntelliJ - Gradle project with several interconnected(!) modules

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, multi-module

I am using IntelliJ IDEA. I am used to work with Maven multi-module projects in it in a way like follows:

1. Create a project.
2. Create modules, say, M1, M2, M0, and M00.
3. Setup all POMs etc → done.

Let's say module `M00` is a public API of my project, which is also used internally by module `M0`, which itself is a common private part of my project which other modules depend on.

That is, `M1` and `M2` both depend on `M0`, while `M0` also depends on `M00`, that is, in modules `M1` and `M2` I can use all the code from modules `M0` and `M00`.

With Maven, this is all as simple as just creating the modules, writing code, and then simply compiling them (with proper POMs configured). With Gradle, however, I cannot access code (classes/methods/...) of one module from inside another.

The only solution I found is to build the aforementioned `M00` module separately from everything and install it in my local Maven repository, then do the same for module `M0`, and then use both modules just like any other external dependencies in other/main modules (`M1` and `M2`).

This means that I have to **waste** really much time doing that monotonous and boring work every time I make any changes to modules `M0` or `M00` (while with Maven, IntelliJ detects code from modules of the same project and uses it automatically, without making me always build and install the "dependencies" every time I make a change).

**Is there any way to make this simpler ("Maven-like")? Because I don't really see any reasons to use Gradle for such a project *otherwise* since it only hardens and slows down the development.**

*P.S.: I am **very** new to Gradle*

> My project structure:

```
torifly
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       └── resources
├── torifly-client
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
├── torifly-protocol
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
├── torifly-sdk
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
├── torifly-server
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
└── torifly-updater
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   ├── java
        │   └── resources
        └── test
            ├── java
            └── resources
```

> Contents of the root 'settings.gradle' file

```
rootProject.name = 'torifly'

include "torifly-client"
include "torifly-protocol"
include "torifly-server"
include "torifly-sdk"
include 'torifly-updater'
```

> Contents of the root `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    }
}
```

> Contents of other (modules') 'build.gradle' files
>
> These files are all the same and only differ in name (`group`)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'net.torifly.protocol'
version '1.0.0'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'me.darksidecode.easysockets', name: 'EasySockets', version: '1.0.0'
}
```

If linked to my "example names" in the question itself, modules `torifly-client` and `torifly-server` may refer to samples `M1` and `M2` respectively, module `torifly-sdk` may be `M00` and `torifly-protocol` could be module `M0`. Module `torifly-updater` is a separate standalone module not connected to any other modules inside this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you just want to setup dependency between your modules. This works basically the same as is would in Maven.

**Module M0 - build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':M00') 
}
```

This has to be done for every inter-module dependency. For more information see [Gradle docs](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/).